# Logout issue on Blazor OIDC client

Tags: c#, blazor, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm having a big issue with a Blazor WebAssembly application that is being integrated with Oidc authentication. The identity server used is Keycloak in version 18.0.2. It does the log in process without any problem, but in the logout throws the error: `Missing parameter: id_token_hint`. I have been reading that is an issue that is noticed by Microsoft but I need a workaround to get it working.